# Is there a way to have one Rails 3.x app use two different cache stores?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails 3.1, I can specify the caching mechanism in `config/environments/*.yml`.  Now, setting it to `:file_store` is a good way to cache Dragonfly images, for example, but of course everything else will be cached as files as well (actions, fragments etc.).

Now, is there a way to have one app use two different cache stores — for example, everything Dragonfly does is stored in `:file_store`, while everything else goes to Memcache?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this article][1]? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729670/how-to-use-multiple-caches-in-rails

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @Ekampp — but it doesn't really apply to me since Dragonfly's caching is not page caching, meaning as soon as I enable Memcache, Dragonfly starts caching its images there. And I was curious whether there's a `Rack::Cache` way to do it so maybe Varnish isn't necessary…

Answer (score 2):

In a word, yes.

`Rack::Cache` [separates cache entries into](http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/storage) a `MetaStore` and an `EntityStore`.

> Using a memory based storage implementation (heap or memcached) for
>   the MetaStore is strongly advised, while a disk based storage
>   implementation (file) is often satisfactory for the EntityStore and
>   uses much less memory.

The following is a suggested configuration of [memcached](http://memcached.org/) via the [dalli gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/dalli).

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => URI.encode("file:#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache/rack/body"),
  :allow_reload => false
}
```

An alternative memory store is [Redis](http://redis.io), which you can configure using [@jodosha](https://github.com/jodosha)'s [redis-store](http://rubygems.org/gems/redis-store).

---

Based on the title of your question, people might arrive here looking for a way to chain multiple caching layers in order of lowest-latency.

This functionality is provided by [@jch](https://github.com/jch)'s [cascade-store](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport-cascadestore) which is another [custom rails cache store](http://intridea.com/posts/writing-a-custom-rails-cache-store). Rails example:

```
config.cache_store = [:cascade_store, :stores => [
  [:memory_store, :size => 5.megabytes, :expires_in => 15.minutes],
  [:mem_cache_store, 'localhost:11211'],
]]
```

Comment: Heroku users might also want to [read the relevant article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-static-assets-rails31) for their platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the `:metastore`/`:entitystore` config was news to me. If I read your first example correctly, action/fragment caching would use `:dalli_store` whereas Rack::Cache would follow its own config?